# Python - Why is reverse geocode throwing a UnicodeDecode error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse-geocoding

I'm following the instructions [at this link](https://pypi.org/project/reverse-geocode/).

The code is as follows:

```
import reverse_geocode
coordinates = (-37.81, 144.96), (31.76, 35.21)
reverse_geocode.search(coordinates)
```

Instead of the output shown at the link, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 464: character maps to <undefined>
```

Note that it isn't an import problem; I could import the module fine with Python3.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Is that the entire error traceback?

Comment: unfortunately it seems like a Windows specific issue (which was not resolved): https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/1414

Comment: "I could import the module fine with Python3" But it throws the error in Python2? You've tagged the question [tag:python-3.x]. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be [an issue with `reverse_geocode`](https://github.com/richardpenman/reverse_geocode/issues/2).  This issue has been fixed in the source code as of July, but this fix has yet to make its way into a release.

Until then, the workaround is to modify `Lib\site-packages\reverse_geocode\__init__.py` under wherever you have Python installed.  Edit this file and add the argument `encoding="utf-8"` to all calls to `open()`.

Answer (score 0):

modify Lib\site-packages\reverse_geocode_*init*_.py and edit open(,encoding="utf-8")